# GCP unexpired tokens

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, token, gcloud

First off, I'll admit that I'm not even sure I'm going down the right path with the right questions.  I've been thrown into the deep end as my company moves into GCP and am learning on the fly.

The situation I've got is a developer was able to use a token from another user to perform some work.  What is really bad is the owner of the token left the company awhile ago.  In admin.google.com I verified the user is suspended which shows me that our AD integration is working.

My assumption is the old user was issued a token somewhere with a very long and unacceptable time to live.  Which leads me to two questions.  The first is there a way I can find any and all tokens issued to this user?  The second is if I'm going to be going down this rabbit hole, is there a way I can search for all long lived tokens?

I'm hoping for a gcloud solution that I can script out for formatting and any parsing I might need to do to get useable/human readable formatting without lots of extra inforamtion.

Comment: It's not possible for a User account to have a long-lived access token. It's possible that the User's credentials have been incorrectly revoked and continue to be refreshed. It's more possible that the tokens are being issued to a Service Account that has not been revoked. See [access token lifetime](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/token-types#at-lifetime)

Comment: In the world of authentication and authorization, there are many types of tokens. To answer your question requires knowing what type the token is, what service provides the tokens (the Authority), and which service accepted the token. It is not clear which cloud you are referring to. The longest lifetime for a Google OAuth token is 12 hours. API keys and Client credentials do not expire. Then there are encryption keys, Signed URLs, etc. Edit your question with details.

Comment: For the most part, there are no APIs to list tokens. Tokens are usually signed data blobs. Those tokens are not stored in Google Cloud. The signature is used to validate them. Specifically tokens are signed with an RSA private key and validated using the RSA public key.

Comment: I recommend that you pull in a team member with experience in this area. Authentication, authorization, public key cryptography, and encryption are complex specialties.

Comment: It would be helpful perhaps too if you explained what the other developer did when they "use a token from another user", If you have an access or identity token, you can use Google's OAuth endpoint to verify it. This will enumerate the email address of the User or Service Account against which it was issue, scopes, expiry etc. `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token={accessToken}` or `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token={id_token}`.

Comment: There's also a useful and mostly unknown CLI tool called [oauth2l](https://github.com/google/oauth2l) that does much the same.